# Unable to COUNTROWS dataset B from tablix with dataset A scope, looking for alternate solutions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder

I have 2 datasets (dsMain, dsHoliday). I've been trying to get the number of holidays between the DateStart and DateEnd of a tablix with a dataset scope dsMain, but as expected it isn't working since the dsHoliday is outside of the tablix's dataset scope.

I'd like to mention, dsMain is pulled from a SQL query while the dsHoliday is pulled from a Power BI dataset (it was originally an Excel file that I loaded into a PBI dataset so that I can pull it into PBI Report Builder).

I only need to get the number of holidays between the two dates for each record. That said, is there some other way I can make this work given the circumstances? I tried the formula below but was getting an error (depending on whether I add it as a calculated field or a field expression). Is it possible maybe to use both dates as a LOOKUPSET condition to pull the dates into just one text line and count the number of date values in the combined text? (eg: for ID:1, "05/02/2022, 05/03/2022")

Any leads or alternate solutions I can try?

```
=SUM(
IIF(Fields!Date.Value >= Fields!DateStart.Value AND Fields!Date.Value <= Fields!DateEnd.Value, 1, 0),
"dsHoliday"
)
```

Error (when adding formula as an expression):

> The Value expression for the text box 'Textbox2' refers to the field 'DateStart'.
> Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or,
> if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields
> must use the correct case.

Error (when adding formula as a calculated field):

> The expression used for the calculated field 'Test' includes an aggregate,
> RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function. Aggregate, RowNumber,
> RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions cannot be used in calculated
> field expressions.

Sample dataset dsMain:

| ID | Country | DateStart | DateEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tunisia | 05/01/2022 | 05/03/2022 |
| 2 | Tunisia | 05/02/2022 | 05/04/2022 |
| 3 | Vietnam | 05/03/2022 | 05/03/2022 |
| 4 | Vietnam | 05/01/2022 | 05/04/2022 |
| 5 | Tunisia | 05/01/2022 | 05/01/2022 |

Sample dataset dsHoliday:

| Country | Date | IsHoliday | IsWeekend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tunisia | 05/02/2022 | TRUE | FALSE |
| Tunisia | 05/03/2022 | TRUE | FALSE |
| Vietnam | 05/02/2022 | TRUE | FALSE |
| Vietnam | 05/03/2022 | TRUE | FALSE |

Comment: As far as I know you won't be able to do this. Is there any reason you cannot put the data into your database? You could create your Power BI dataset from that for consistency. Once in the database you could easily include it in you main dataset. You could even use openrowset to directly access the excel file and join to it in your dataset query but that seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: It's just an Excel file, I'm afraid. 

About getting the row count of the dsHoliday dataset - is there a way I can add this as a query field in the dsMain dataset? I tried `SELECT COUNT(Date) FROM dsHoliday WHERE DATE BETWEEN DateStart AND DateEnd` and that just returned a blank table. Or maybe use an SQL query as a field expression that will run on a per row basis in the tablix? I'm not sure if this will work though as the dsHoliday dataset is a PBI dataset and not pulled via SQL like dsMain.

Comment: The only way to include the data in dsHoliday in your dsMain dataset would be as I explained earlier... either add it to your database then update your dsMain dataset query to include the additional data or if the excel file is somewhere the SQL server can 'see' then use OPENROWSET in you dsMain dataaset query to read the excel file directly.